# Solidity - get method for solidity an array of struct object

Tags: solidity, ether

I wouldlike to have get method for access an array of my object :

```
struct WalletTeam{
        address wallet;
        uint256 amount;
    }
    
    WalletTeam[] walletTeam;

function getWallet() public view returns (WalletTeam memory)
    {
        return walletTeam;
    }
```

But it seems not working... what is the best way to have all address and amount from the array walletTeam ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to return an array in order to work:

```
function getWallet() public view returns (WalletTeam[] memory)
{
    return walletTeam;
}
```